# Exposed form don't have class attribute

Tags: 8, forms

In a `form_alter`, I simply want to add a class to an exposed form (this code works for a custom form) :

```
$form['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my_class';
```

But neither my class nor the default class (`views-exposed-form`, I can see it in `$form['#attributes']`) is printed in front in the `form` tag.

Any idea?

Comment: Where do you set this class? Which function exactly?

Comment: In the theme, hook_form_alter()

Answer (score 0):

I guess `hook_form_alter` is not the right place to set attributes. But I may be wrong. What surely works is to set attributes in a preprocess function.

The following snippet adds the form ID as CSS class to every form. You could easily wrap some if-request around this to only fire on certain forms checking for `$variables['element']['#form_id']`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_form(&$variables) {

  // Add form ID as class to form attributes.
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'form';
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'form-' . str_replace('_', '-', $variables['element']['#form_id']);
}
```